# solana local chain

Tags: solana-test-validator, testing

i try to running solana in local my environment with help of solana-test-validator and its running in local environment absolute fine.

but i have some doubt it create its own genesis config with default keypair

after that i try to running solana with my own genesis config data

here it is :

./target/release/solana-genesis 
--bootstrap-stake-authorized-pubkey ./test-ledger/validator-keypair.json 
--bootstrap-validator ./test-ledger/validator-keypair.json 
./test-ledger/vote-account-keypair.json 
./test-ledger/stake-account-keypair.json 
--bootstrap-validator-lamports 500000000000 
--bootstrap-validator-stake-lamports 10000000000 
--cluster-type mainnet-beta 
--faucet-lamports 999999999999999 
--faucet-pubkey ./test-ledger/faucet-keypair.json \
--fee-burn-percentage 50 
--hashes-per-tick sleep 
--inflation none 
--lamports-per-byte-year 200 
--ledger test-ledger 
--rent-burn-percentage 10 
--rent-exemption-threshold 1 
--slots-per-epoch 100 
--target-signatures-per-slot 1 
--target-tick-duration 100 
--ticks-per-slot 3 
--vote-commission-percentage 10 
--max-genesis-archive-unpacked-size 10485760

and run this config by this binary file

./target/release/solana-validator --identity test-ledger/validator-keypair.json --ledger test-ledger --log test-ledger/log.log --no-voting --full-rpc-api --authorized-voter ./test-ledger/validator-keypair.json --vote-account test-ledger/vote-account-keypair.json run

but by this method chain is not running in stable condition
i always a get error

"[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2024-03-17T13:57:36.800193000Z [0m[1m[31mERROR[0m solana_core::replay_stage[0m[38;5;8m][0m 3CcE56AXBZgXykmoyaA44emWo2EDgjAnWE6XNhPmEEMY No next leader found"

any solution to run solana chain in my local system with my own config

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but try removing the `--no-voting` flag when you run the validator.

The error says "No next leader found", which makes sense because the only possible leader, the bootstrap node, isn't voting.